# How to make VSF inbound endpoint fail according to some conditions

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

There is my case to waiting for TXT files and then calling a REST api according to the file. Hence, I create a proxy service such as:

```
<proxy name="vsf-to-rest" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
        <property expression="$trp:FILE_NAME" name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var filename = mc.getProperty('filename');
            var s = filename.split('_');
            mc.setProperty('a', s[0]);
            mc.setProperty('b', s[1]);]]></script>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"a":"$1", "b":"$2"}</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('a')" literal="true"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('b')" literal="true"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <call>
            <endpoint key="mock-task-endpoint"/>
        </call>
        <drop/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:////Users/me/vsf/in</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:////Users/me/vsf/failed</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.txt</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:file:////Users/me/vsf/proceeded</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The problem is how to make the sequence fail according to the HTTP status of REST api (viz. 4xx and 5xx). I tried to use `switch` and `makefault` mediation, but all input files are moved to `proceeded` folder and there are no files in `failed` even if REST api returns 4xx or 5xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior in the EI. The MoveAfterFailure occurs only in a situation where an error occurs while reading the file or processing the file. If any error occurs in the mediation such as an endpoint call failure it will not be considered a failure for VFS.

If you want to move the file from the processed folder to the failed folder based on the endpoint call, you can implement a file connector [1] within a switch mediator (to evaluate the endpoint response code) after the endpoint call to move the file from processed folder to failed folder (I have not tested this locally).

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-move

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind reply. According to your info., the file will be moved to `proceeded` or `failed` folder just at the end of the VSF inbound endpoint, and even if any error occurs in the further sequence, the file will not be moved anymore. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Move after failure only triggers if axis2 fault/ IO error thrown in the mediation sequence.

Hence, you can do the following to achieve your requirement.

**Move the file based on the status code**

```
<filter source="$ctx:RESPONSE_STATUS" regex="500">
    <then>
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address uri="vfs:file:////Users/me/vsf/failed"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </then>
</filter>
```

*For actual faulty messages*

1. Define a sequence and reference the fault sequence in the proxy as follows.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="errorSequence">
  <log level="custom">
    <property name="MESSAGE" value="ERROR OCCURRED"/>
  </log>
  <property name="ERROR_STATUS" expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE"/>
  <!-- log some data -->
  <log level="custom">
    <property name="FILE_NAME" expression="$ctx:FILE"/>
    <property name="FILE_CONTENT" expression="$ctx:CONTENT"/>
    <property name="STATUS" expression="$ctx:ERROR_STATUS"/>
  </log>
  <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address uri="vfs:file:////Users/me/vsf/failed"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </then>

</sequence>
```

2. Reference the error sequence in the proxy.

Can you give a try with the above approach?

Thanks,
Dileepa

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice. However, I'm afraid the solution is negative. The message becomes HTTP response after calling the REST api endpoint but the original file, so using send mediation after it will just save the HTTP  response to a file in the `failed` folder.

Comment: you are correct @TonnyTc. please apologize for the incomplete answer. please refer to the complete code from here https://www.codepile.net/pile/1bwXg0r7

Comment: I'm afraid there is still an issue in the code that one file has been moved to the `proceeded` folder at the end of vfs inbound endpoint, and it should be deleted then if a new file is created on the `failed` folder according to your solution. However, there is nothing handling the file in `proceeded` folder. Eventurally, I decided to accept Shanaka's solution to use file connector. Thanks a lot for your time again!